# React Native Bottom Navigation load android existing fragment

Tags: android-fragments, react-native

Hi All I am new to React Native and working on a migration project (Android native to Recat native)
I have migrated the native android Bottom Navigation to react native material bottom navigation.

But don't know how to link existing native fragments with this new bottom navigation.

can someone please guide me or share some samples to meet this requirement?

Appreciate any help or reference code.